Killing ants with Borax that has been mixed with sugar upon cottonballs: How should I replace the bait?
I have tried to use borax to kill ants. Upon first application, I made a paste using sugar and borax then I soaked cottonballs and placed in areas where I saw ant activity.
Now the cottonballs are wet but covered with a crust of the solution that has dried out. Should I throw them away and make a new one, or wet it and leave it?
Also, I do not know whether making the paste and leaving it in small dishes is also a solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As long as the poison is still there, just add more water if it dries out.
But the cotton balls aren't essential, and it doesn't have to be paste.
A liquid solution sitting in bottle caps (or even spilled on the floor, or almost any setup that the ants can access without drowning) works fine. If it's drinkable and tastes like sugar, the ants will take it.
But if the ants are ignoring it, know that some types prefer it with a little peanut butter added.

So I can mix cocacola or any type of sugary beverage (fanta,sprite,juice) with borax and will do the job just fine?

@DimitriosDesyllas, the trick is to find something that the ants like to eat, and then contaminate it with the borax. Most ants are happy with sugar water, but some have preferences. You could experiment by setting out several containers of different solutions and see if one is more popular than the others. You could even compare different concentrations of sugar. See what works best for your specific ants.

Or mix the borax with honey and make streaks or blobs of the mix across a piece of plastic, a tile, etc. So the ants can gather round without needing to walk in it. Place an upturned plant pot over the tile, with gaps under, so other creatures can't get to it.
